# Createing a string conditional base on different values stored in string , tuples

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, tuples

I have a set of fields(strings), under different structures them I want to create a string from them;

1. I have a set of default fields as a tuple: `('created_at', 'active')`
2. `r_field` is received as argument, and can be `None`, `'all'` or a tuple `('descr', city')`
3. A function `set_fields`, that transform fields in string:

   ```
   def set_fields(fields=None, particle=None):

       default_fields = ('created_at', 'active')
       default_fields = ', '.join([(particle + '.' if particle else "") + s for s in default_fields])
       if isinstance(fields, tuple):
           fields = default_fields + ', ' + ", ".join([(particle + '.' if particle else "") + s for s in fields])
       elif isinstance(fields, str) and fields == 'all':
           fields = '*'
       else:
           fields = default_fields
       return fields
   ```

The `set_fields` is called by other functions. This functions get the fields and do other operations with them or their values.

```
def rodan(fields=None)
    set_fields=(fields=(fields, 'is_bold'), particle='c')
    .................
```

The thing is that each method, can add by themselves other fields like `is_bold`

Example 1:

```
rodan(fields=('name', 'prime'))
```

Result:

```
c.created_at, c.active, c.is_bold, c.name, c.prime
```

Example 2:

```
rodan()
```

Result:

```
c.created_at, c.active, c.is_bold
```

Example 3:

```
rodan(fields='all')
```

Result:

```
*
```

My function work, but doesn't treat when a function needs to add other default fields like `'is_bold'`, besides the general default ones, added for all other functions that call `set_fields`. Also I'm not sure if my approach is optimal, for what I want to achieve.

Comment: *2. `r_field` is received as argument...* did you mean `fields`? There's no reference of `r_field` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question.  Did you mean you wanted to handle additional default fields called by other methods? If so it's a simple addition of optional `args`:

```
def set_fields(fields=None, particle=None, addl_def_fields=None):

    default_fields = ('created_at', 'active')
    # additional handling for other default fields
    if addl_def_fields:
        if isinstance(addl_def_fields, tuple):
            default_fields += addl_def_fields
        elif isinstance(addl_def_fields, str):
            default_fields += (addl_def_fields, )

    # default fields will now contain all your added defaults.
    # ... rest of your codes
```

---

Now when your other functions reference `set_fields` just add the new keyword `addl_def_fields=('is_bold', 'is_italics')` when you call:

```
def rodan(fields=None)
    set_fields=(fields=fields, particle='c', addl_def_fields=('is_bold', 'is_italics'))
    .................
```